# Append value to Hashfield

Tags: node.js, hash, redis, append

Redis [is able to append](http://redis.io/commands/append) a string to the value of a `key`. Instead of a normal key, I need to append to the value of a `Hashfield`. I am currently solving it the obvious way:

```
redis.HGET('hash', 'field2append', function(err, reply){
    redis.HSET('hash', 'field2append', reply + appendString);
});
```

Since the setup involves clusters in multiple physical (node.js) servers, the above could cause data loss due to the time taken between node receiving the value and setting it again (in case another server is updating the same field at the same time).

Is there a safer way to `append` a string to the `value` of a `hashfield`?

Comment: Please explain what you're asking. You want to append to the name of the hash? one of the keys in the hash? one of the values? Give an example.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do this either through [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) (as in a pipeline), or through a [Lua script](http://www.redisgreen.net/blog/2013/03/18/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/) running all logic on the server side. Because Redis is single threaded, when you run a transaction or a lua script, *it will block everything else from running until it finishes*. In this way, you'll be able to guarantee that data loss for the reasons you mentioned will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible without risking a race condition?

Redis is single-threaded.

> I need to (atomically) append to a Hashfield (string).

The key for a hashfield? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a single-threaded process. There is no race condition problem.